# Variable in shell script not interpreted unless run as su

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, aws-code-deploy

I have the following script I deploy on AWS EC2 instances as part of the deployment  (CodeDeploy) process:

```
# export ipaddres                                                                                                                                                                                 
export DOCKERHOSTIP=`/sbin/ip addr | grep 'eth0' | grep 'inet' | cut -d'/' -f1 | awk '{print $2}'`                                                                                                

echo "Need to fix the file_transfers folder to use the ENV var"                                                                                                                                   
docker run --name gateway -p 30089:30089/udp -p 2000:2000/udp -p 30089:30089 -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --restart=always -v /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs -v /var/log/gateway:/var/log -v /hom
e/fileTransfers:/home/gateway/fileTransfers --env-file=/etc/gateway/deployment.env --add-host dockerhost:$DOCKERHOSTIP --log-driver=syslog -d apprepo/gateway:$ENV 

sleep 30                                                                                                                                                                                          
docker cp /etc/gateway/htaccess gateway:/home/src/www-server/.htaccess
```

This script is fairly generic as it is used across AWS VPC's in order to bring up a Docker container running a web service. In two (**US, EUROPE**) VPC's this script works **perfectly**. In another (**APAC**, Singapore to be specific) the `$ENV` **variable does not get interpreted** which results in the Docker container not launching.

If I change to 'su' and run the script the `$ENV` is interpreted properly and the Docker container is started.

I have checked the environment variables which are set up in the machine prior to the deployment process. Here is that output:

```
    [ec2-user@ip-10-13-10-202 deployment-archive]$ printenv                                                                                                                                           
    INSTALLER=/tmp/2194023707117373959-bomgar-scc-installer.bin                                                                                                                                       
    LESS_TERMCAP_mb=                                                                                                                                                                                  
    HOSTNAME=ip-nn-nn-nn-nnn
    LESS_TERMCAP_md=                                                                                                                                                                                  
    LESS_TERMCAP_me=                                                                                                                                                                                  
    SILENT_MESSAGE_BOX=1                                                                                                                                                                              
    TERM=xterm                                                                                                                                                                                        
    SHELL=/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                   
    HISTSIZE=1000                                                                                                                                                                                     
    EC2_AMITOOL_HOME=/opt/aws/amitools/ec2                                                                                                                                                            
    SSH_CLIENT=nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn 20042 22                                                                                                                                                                  
    LESS_TERMCAP_ue=                                                                                                                                                                                  
    SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0                                                                                                                                                                                
    USER=ec2-user                                                                                                                                                                                     
    EC2_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/ec2                                                                                                                                                                    
    ENV=prod                                                                                                                                                                                          
    LESS_TERMCAP_us=                                                                                                                                                                                  
    MAIL=/var/spool/mail/ec2-user
  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin             
    PWD=/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/9924825a-137c-4006-80da-83fece29e3c6/d-T93G4OTJT/deployment-archive                                                                                     
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre                                                                                                                                                                        
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8                                                                                                                                                                                  
    AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/mon                                                                                                                                                         
    HISTCONTROL=ignoredups                                                                                                                                                                            
    SHLVL=10                                                                                                                                                                                          
    HOME=/home/ec2-user                                                                                                                                                                               
    AWS_PATH=/opt/aws                                                                                                                                                                                 
    AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/as                                                                                                                                                        
    LOGNAME=ec2-user                                                                                                                                                                                  
    AWS_ELB_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/elb                                                                                                                                                                
    SSH_CONNECTION=nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn 20042 nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn 22                                                                                                                                                 
    UNPACK_DIR=/tmp/deleteme-bomgar-scc-20171117-000702.8936.8936                                                                                                                                     
    LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s                                                                                                                                                                
    NO_SESSION_RESUME=1                                                                                                                                                                               
    LESS_TERMCAP_se=                                                                                                                                                                                  
    _=/usr/bin/printenv                                                                                                                                                                               
    OLDPWD=/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/9924825a-137c-4006-80da-83fece29e3c6/d-T93G4OTJT
```

Right there on line 16 of the output:

```
ENV=prod
```

*Is there anything obvious I am missing?* The VPC in Singapore was created exactly as the others, US and EUROPE, as we use scripting to spin up our AWS VPC's.

NOTE: We had, at one point, determined the Singapore EC2's did not have certain Python facilities installed which are installed as part of the AMI (machine images) used for the EC2's but Python should have no effect on environment variables.

*If I am not missing something obvious is there something I can do to make sure the `$ENV` variable will be interpreted in the script properly which will not affect other VPC's?* Doing one-off scripts for each VPC defeats the purpose of being able to deploy our web service as needed globally.

Comment: Bash only looks at `ENV` when started as `sh` or in posix mode.

Comment: It is started as `sh` @cdarke